# onMouseOut Event is not working in my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in my page.

```
  <div class="MenuItemContainer">
                <a href="javascript:ShowHelpMenu()">
                    <div class="MenuItemContent">
                        <div>
                            <img src="/Content/TopMenu/Icons/Help.png" alt="Help" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Help
                        </div>
                        <div id="divHelpMenu" class="HelpMenuDisplayDiv" style="z-index:9999; width: 400px;margin: 10px 20px; background-color:Aqua" onmouseout="HideHelpMenu()">
                        <%=Session["helpUrls"]%> 
                       <%-- <%=Session["Links"]%> 
                       --%>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

This is my Functions

```
function ShowHelpMenu() {
$("#divHelpMenu").css("display","block");
}
function HideHelpMenu() {
$("#divHelpMenu").css("display","none");
}
```

When I click on Help Link I can display all the Links but when I mouseover on the links my Div  tag is closing. onmouseout event is not firing when I mouse out from the div tag.

its closing when I mouse in on HTML links.

Thanks

Comment: You're using jQuery. Why are you still writing JS event handlers in your HTML?

Comment: I doubt this will fix it, but maybe insert a semicolon after `HideHelpMenu()` (in the HTML)?
Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: So what your saying is if we use something like this it wont work? thanks

Comment: Like Matt said, why don't you try the jQuery route with the hover event handlers: http://api.jquery.com/hover/.

Comment: 1. You're missing a `</a>`. 2. The PHP code is irrelevant here. Please show the **generated** markup, which is what the browser & client-side JS will actually see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divHelpMenu').hover(function () {
        $("#divHelpMenu").css("display", "block");
    }, function () {
        $("#divHelpMenu").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought you wanted the help menu to show when someone clicked, not when they hovered over it. You need to be more clear in your question next time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your mouse out code on the wrong element, I think you'd want it on the MenuItemContainer div. You could also remove your inline mouse out code and bind the event to the correct container when you show the help div, like this:

```
function ShowHelpMenu() {
    $("#divHelpMenu").css("display","block");
    $('#MenuItemContainer').bind('mouseout.helpmenu', HideHelpMenu);
}
function HideHelpMenu() {
    $("#divHelpMenu").css("display","none");
    $('#MenuItemContainer').unbind('mouseout.helpmenu');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing some closing tags. Try next HTML markup:

```
<div class="MenuItemContainer">
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:ShowHelpMenu();return false;">
    <div class="MenuItemContent">
      <div><img src="/Content/TopMenu/Icons/Help.png" alt="Help" /></div>
        <div>Help</div>
    </div>
  </a><br/>
  <div id="divHelpMenu" class="HelpMenuDisplayDiv" 
    style="display:none;z-index:9999; width: 400px;margin: 10px 20px; background-color:Aqua" 
    onmouseout="HideHelpMenu()">
        Link1<br/>
        Link2<br/>
        Link3<br/>
        Link4<br/>
        Link5<br/>
        Link6<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```